# what should be the initial data in Future provider?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

my Main Class

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => BannerProvider()),
    FutureProvider<List<Datum>>(
      create: (_) => FruitsProvider().getFruitsItem(),
      initialData: [], // what should i provide here since its returning me nothing
      catchError: (context, error) {
        print(error.toString());
        throw Exception(error);
      },
    ),
  ],
  child: MaterialApp(
    home: SafeArea(
      top: false,
      bottom: false,
      child: Container(
        // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/background.png'),
          ),
        ),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          appBar: PreferredSize(
            child: CustomAppBar(),
            preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
          ),
          body: ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
            children: <Widget>[
           BannerClass(),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 5, 15, 20),
                child: const Text(
                  'Shop By Category',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              CategoryButton(),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 15, 20),
                child: const Text(
                  'Fresh Fruits',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // FruitsList(),
              FruitsNewList(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

I dont understand what should be the initial data i provided an empty [] but yeah that just gives me nothing

i wanna provide a horizontal list of fruits in FruitsNewList with api i am calling using a Future Provider
heres the class

```
class FruitsNewList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
List<Datum> fruits = Provider.of<List<Datum>>(context);
return fruits.isEmpty
    ? const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      )
    : SizedBox(
        height: 200,
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: fruits.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
                margin: index == 0
                    ? const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 5, 0)
                    : const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 0),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(fruits[index].title),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          fruits[index].id.toString(),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: const Text(
                            'Add',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                              bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      style: BorderStyle.solid,
                      width: 0.8),
                ));
          },
        ),
      );
     }
     }
```

this class only returning CircularProgressIndicator
instead of the data please help

Comment: Your problem might be that you have a `StatelessWidget` which will not be rebuilt upon receiving data from your future. Try converting `FruistsNewList` to a `StatefulWidget`.

Comment: ok but what should i put inside initial data in FutureProvider?

Comment: `initialData` will be used as the value before the future is resolved. So you can use an empty array if you want, or a progress indicator, or a 'loading' text message etc.

Comment: even making a stateful widget it doesnt work :(

Comment: Update your question with your current code and I will have a look at it.

Comment: its the same i changed it to this again